# Bundler installing gem that's already installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, bundler

I believe I'm misunderstanding the way bundler works, but from the `bundle install` [documentation](http://bundler.io/bundle_install.html) it seems to indicate bundler will use locally installed system gems.

> ...
>
> --system: Install to the system location ($BUNDLE_PATH or $GEM_HOME) even if the bundle was previously installed somewhere else for this application
>
> ...
>
> The --system option is the default. Pass it to switch back after using the --path option as described below.

I'm not using rbenv/rvm or any other Ruby version manager. I'm using ChefDK as my primary development environment, which ships with Ruby and a bunch of preinstalled gems.

The full contents of the Gemfile, there is no Gemfile.lock yet.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.3.1'
```

Local nokogiri installed

```
$ gem list --local | grep nokogiri
nokogiri (1.6.6.2, 1.6.3.1, 1.5.5)
```

System Gem location has nokogiri 1.6.3.1 installed

```
$ echo $GEM_HOME
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0
$ find /Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0 | grep nokogiri | grep 1.6.3.1
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.3.1.gem
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/mkmf.log
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/.autotest
/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/.editorconfig
...
```

However, when I run a bundle install, it tries to install and compile libxml2 for nokogiri.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using mini_portile 0.6.0
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Building libxml2-2.8.0 for nokogiri with the following patches applied:
  - 0001-Fix-parser-local-buffers-size-problems.patch
  - 0002-Fix-entities-local-buffers-size-problems.patch
  - 0003-Fix-an-error-in-previous-commit.patch
  - 0004-Fix-potential-out-of-bound-access.patch
  - 0005-Detect-excessive-entities-expansion-upon-replacement.patch
  - 0006-Do-not-fetch-external-parsed-entities.patch
  - 0007-Enforce-XML_PARSER_EOF-state-handling-through-the-pa.patch
  - 0008-Improve-handling-of-xmlStopParser.patch
  - 0009-Fix-a-couple-of-return-without-value.patch
  - 0010-Keep-non-significant-blanks-node-in-HTML-parser.patch
  - 0011-Do-not-fetch-external-parameter-entities.patch
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT!  Nokogiri builds and uses a packaged version of libxml2.
...
```

What am I missing? How can I force bundler to use the already installed nokogiri 1.6.3.1 (that ships with ChefDK)? I'm trying to avoid having nokogiri compile libxml2 because that fails consistently on many different developer/operations workstations and has caused no end of grief. Thanks.

**Edit**

Thanks to Tim Moore, using `bundle env` I noticed in the output that bundler had shared gems disabled.

```
$ bundle env
Bundler 1.7.12
Ruby 2.1.4 (2014-10-27 patchlevel 265) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
Rubygems 2.4.4
GEM_HOME /Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0
GEM_PATH /Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0:/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0

Bundler settings
  disable_shared_gems
    Set for the current user (/Users/arthur/.bundle/config): "1"


Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
...
```

Looking at the `~/.bundle/config`, sure enough the global config was set.

```
---
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
```

Once removed, Bundler resolves nokogiri 1.6.3.1 correctly and doesn't try reinstalling it. This setting should not be there by default, by default bundler installs with `--system`. I must have set this setting many months back and forgot I did.

Comment: Can that be because some other gem is pulling a different version of nokogiri as a dependency?

Comment: But there's only one gem in the Gemfile.

Comment: Hm.. so that's the full Gemfile. Srry then, no idea.

Comment: can you post the lock file ? any version difference in the gemfile lock ?

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d I had removed the lock file, just trying to build from scratch.

Comment: Just an idea: what gives `bundle exec ruby -rubygems -e "puts Gem::dir"` and `bundle exec echo $GEM_HOME`. Sounds like bundle does not use the same path as yours, try your commands within bundle exec to see what changes.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai, they all point to `/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0` which has nokogiri 1.6.3.1 in the gems folder `/Users/arthur/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running `bundle env` to verify that the install location is what you expect.

If not, check whether there is a `.bundle/config` or `~/.bundle/config` file overriding the install path. The output of `bundle env` will tell you what configuration it is using and how it was determined (i.e., which file it was in or whether it was picked up from an environment variable).

Comment: I get this in the output: `Bundler settings
  disable_shared_gems
    Set for the current user (/Users/arthur/.bundle/config): "1"`, is that it?

Comment: That setting does disable the default of `--system` but it usually doesn't appear by itself without a `path` setting. Try running `bundle install --system` explicitly to reset to the default behaviour.

Comment: That was it!! It was that setting! `--system` is the default, which is why I never thought Bundler would be doing something different. Apparently at some point I put `BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'` in my `~/.bundle/config` and that's why `--system` wasn't enabled. This totally explains it, thank you so much!

Comment: Something slightly confusing about Bundler is that it saves flags, so even though `--system` is the default in a clean project, if you ever run `bundle install` with any other flags, those get stored in the config file and effectively change the defaults for future runs.

Comment: Yeah, that must have happened at some point long ago, and caused all this confusion. Thanks again for clearing this up!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all contents of gemfile.lock file. Save the file. Run bundle install again.

Comment: Unfortunately this is running `bundle install` without a `Gemfile.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods. In gemfile you can specify the path which will force bundle to use from there.

```
gem "my_gem", :path => "path to gem"
```

As i see the issue is with the default paths here. Try doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately nokogiri doesn't [include a gemspec](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/Y_U_NO_GEMSPEC.md). So I get `Could not find gem 'nokogiri (>= 0) ruby' in source at /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1.`

Answer (score 0):

ChefDK doesn't install gems globally, it installs them under `/opt/chefdk` so they won't interfere with "your" global gems. I suggest you leave ChefDK gems isolated as they should be.

Comment: I'm using Chef as the primary development environment, and all locally installed gems go into `~/.chefdk`. My goal is to try and explicitly *use* the ChefDK installed nokogiri so when other Chef developers do `bundle install`, Bundler doesn't try to install nokogiri (and thereby fail the compilation process), but instead uses the nokogiri already there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper `bundler` and `gem`.  If you're using ChefDK, then it includes its own `bundler` and `gem` executables.  They should be inside the `/opt/chefdk` directory, I believe under `/opt/chefdk/embedded` (I don't use chefdk, so I can be 100% sure of that).

To work 100% inside that ruby install, you need to ensure that the `chefdk` binaries are in your path before the other ruby related binaries. You can verify that with `which ruby` `which gem` and `which bundle`.

All that said, you really SHOULDN'T be messing with the ruby install for chefdk.  It's embedded for a reason, so that you don't accidentally mess it up.  I'd suggest you stick with the system ruby for your own work, and let Chef handle its ruby.

Comment: I'm using [ChefDK as my primary development environment](https://github.com/chef/chef-dk#using-chefdk-as-your-primary-development-environment), and mostly this is for cookbook development.

Answer (score 0):

From Bundler [docs](http://bundler.io/v1.9/bundle_install.html):

> --path: Specify a different path than the system default ($BUNDLE_PATH or $GEM_HOME). **Bundler will remember this value for future installs on
>   this machine**

Your bundler may have cached a --path specified install command. 
Try:

```
bundle install --system
```

This will tell bundler to use the system installed gems as opposed to downloading new gem copies to a folder specific gem collection.